# How to apply decimal and thousand separator to numbers in cbar?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to apply decimal and thousands separator to `cbar` in Seaborm plot in order to see numbers formatted like this: `4.294.967.295,00`.
I know how to format `xaxis` and `yaxis`, but cannot apply this formating to `cbar`.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, linewidths=.5)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x,p: str(int(x))+":00"))
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `str(int(x))` with `format(int(x), 'd.')`?

Comment: @DomWeldon I think the example is just here to show that he knows how to do formating for the `yaxis` with an arbitrary formating.

Comment: @DomWeldon: jadsq is right. I showed an example for `yaxis`, but I do not know how to apply formatting to `cbar`. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

This template code should help you out.  Takes an unformatted number, adds the "," before the last 2 digits, then goes through and adds the "." every 3 characters.

```
number = "1000000000"
temp = ""
temp += number[:-2] + "," + number[-2:]
e = list(temp.split(",")[0])
for i in range(len(e))[::-3][1:]:
    e.insert(i+1,".")
result = "".join(e)+","+temp.split(",")[1]
print(result)
```

This is result for the static number I gave.: 10.000.000,00

Comment: Ok, but how to I apply it to `cbar`?

Comment: @Dinosaurius I'm not too familiar with cbar, I assume you can turn my code into a python function that cbar calls to return the format, or am I wrong?

Comment: My principal issue is that I do not know how to access `cbar` of seaborn's heatmap.